# Gatling :- Compare web service Json response using jsonFileFeeder

Tags: json, performance, scala, performance-testing, gatling

I'm using JSON feeder to compare JSON output by web services as follows,

```
 val jsonFileFeeder = jsonFile("test_data.json")

    val strategy = (value: Option[String], session: Session) => value.map { jsonFileFeeder =>
      val result = JSONCompare.compareJSON("expectedStr", "actualStr", JSONCompareMode.STRICT)
      if (result.failed) Failure(result.getMessage)
      else Success(value)
      }.getOrElse(Failure("Missing body"))

      val login = exec(http("Login")
       .get("/login"))
      .pause(1)
      .feed(feeder)
      .exec(http("authorization")
        .post("/auth")
        .headers(headers_10)
        .queryParam("""email""", "${email}")
        .queryParam("""password""", "${password}")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(bodyString.matchWith(strategy)))
      .pause(1)
```

But it throws error

```
value matchWith is not a member of io.gatling.core.check.DefaultFindChe
ckBuilder[io.gatling.http.check.HttpCheck,io.gatling.http.response.Response,String,String]
15:10:01.963 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -         .check(bodyString.matchWith(jsonFileFeeder)))

s\lib\Login.scala:18: not found: value JSONCompare
15:10:05.224 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ -       val result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(jsonFileFeeder, j
sonFileFeeder, JSONCompareMode.STRICT)
               ^
15:10:05.631 [ERROR] i.g.a.ZincCompiler$ - two errors found
Compilation failed
```

Comment: The errors seem to suggest that the `matchWith` function and `JSONCompare` object don't exist - which is true, there's no such code in Gatling (I guess `JSONCompare` is from JSONAssert, not sure about `matchWith`). Whilst it's probably possible to fix up this code, have you considered using jsonPath, which I suspect will prove easier and more flexible?

Comment: @James_pic :- Could you please add some code snipet , how can I use JSONFeeder to compare web service JSON responses ?

Comment: How big is the JSON response? Also, is it important that it matches exactly, or would it be satisfactory to just check one or two elements of the returned JSON?

Comment: JSON object may be much large, to mach one or two elements that already implemented using  .check(jsonPath("$..videos[0].name").saveAs("name")), now i'm planing to do accuracy testing kind of stuff. So basically I want to compare whole JSON object.

Comment: I want to match JSON exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample script that semantically compares a JSON response with expected output:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.json.Jackson
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  lazy val expectedJson = Jackson.parse(
      getClass.getResourceAsStream("/output.json"),
      UTF_8
    )

  val scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
    .exec(http("request_1")
      .get("http://localhost:8000/output.json")
      .check(bodyString.transform(Jackson.parse).is(expectedJson))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
}
```

It assumes there is a file `output.json` in the `resources` directory (the directory that also contains your `data` and `request-bodies`).

However, I think you should carefully consider whether this solution is right for your needs. It won't scale as well as JSONPath or regex checks (especially for large JSON files), it's inflexible, and it seems more like a functional testing task than a performance task. I suspect that if you're trying to compare JSON files in this way, then you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Note that it doesn't use `jsonFile`, as `jsonFile` is designed for use as a feeder, whereas I suspect you want to compare a single request with a hard-coded response. However, `jsonFile` may prove useful if you will be making a number of different requests with different parameters and expect different (known) responses. Here's an example script that takes this approach:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.json.Jackson
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
  val myFeed = jsonFile("json_data.json").circular

  val scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
    .feed(myFeed)
    .exec(http("request_1")
      .get("${targetUrl}")
      .check(bodyString.transform(Jackson.parse).is("${expectedResponse}"))
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2)))
}
```

It assumes there is a json resource in `data/json_data.json`, that looks something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "targetUrl":"http://localhost:8000/failure.json",
    "expectedResponse":
      {
        "success": false,
        "message": "Request Failed"
      }
  },
  {
    "targetUrl":"http://localhost:8000/success.json",
    "expectedResponse":
      {
        "success": true,
        "message": "Request Succeeded"
      }
  }
]
```

The `expectedResponse` should be the exact JSON you expect to get back from the server. And of course you don't just have to parameterise `targetUrl`, you can parameterise whatever you want in this way.

As an aside, you may also be interested to know that Gatling 2.1 is expected to allow comparing an response with a file without using hacks like these (although the current development version only supports comparing byte-for-byte, not comparing-as-json).

Comment: Thanks @James :- yes in this i'm trying to do accuracy testing kind of stuff.

Comment: I have a gatling-charts-highcharts-2.0.0-RC3\user-files\data\output.json file and I tried your code with '\output.json' and without backslash but it fails with error message.                   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in `user-files`, not `user-files\data`, and the *front* slash is necessary. Sorry I couldn't give you the exact name of the directory to put it in - Gatling has a couple of different configurations you can use it in, and the precise location of the files can vary (I'm using it with Maven, which keeps resources in the `resources` directory).

Comment: How I can deal with this please, Request 'authorization' failed: bodyString transform.is([{Message=Success, Api_key=Xxxx.j41Av, Pcode=Xxxx}]),
 but actually found {Message=Success, Api_key=Xxxx.j41Av, Pcode=Xxxx}

Comment: It looks like your actual response doesn't match the expected response. Notice that your expected response is an array containing an object, whereas your actual response is just an object (the square brackets are easy to miss). This is either a bug in the system-under-test, or your expected response is wrong - most likely a hangover from attempting to use `jsonFeed` to handle this.

Comment: I suspect you want fewer square brackets, not more. My approach is based on having data in `output.json` that exactly matches what you expect back from the server, which looks to be a plain object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60980/discussion-between-swapnil-and-james-pic).